# Wordpress custom post type in wrong taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I've add a custom post type with custom taxonomies. I've also added rewrite rules in order to handle following urls:

```
courses/languages/english/english-course
```

where courses is the base slug, **languages** and **english** are taxonomy slugs and **english-course** is my custom post. english-course is a child taxonomy of languages and english-course has been categorized in english-course.
My rewrite rule is:

```
courses/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$  => index.php?thr_course=$matches[3]
```

Everything works fine but *any* categories are permitted using this syntax. All following urls are legitimate and work as well:

> 1. courses/languages/**french**/english-course
> 2. course/products/**english**/english-course
> 3. course/**anycategory**/**anycategory2**/english-course

My rewrite rule is pretty obvious: it only matches my post name ignoring which categories it belongs to.
Where and how should I implement a check in order to return 404 
if post exists but parent taxonomies are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think WordPrss will not give you a solution for your customization automatically. Fetch other parameters from like parent / child category from URL, similar to thr_course parameter. Use this parameter in your query to narrow down your result.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where should I handle this? Is there any hook?